# How to handle hooked WSARecv

Tags: c, sockets, winapi, hook

I'm working on a project that involves hooking `WSARecv`. I know how to hook this function, I mean its just the same as hooking another function. Anyway the hard part is when `WSARecv` is used to perform overlapped operations. The idea is that when an application receives data to intercept that and be possible to modify this, I'm using pipes for this. The native DLL tunnels all data to a managed 'server'. This processes the input etc and returns it back to the native DLL. This works great for `WSASend`, `send` and `recv`. However the hard part is when an application uses overlapped sockets.

So I need the received data first before I can process it, this is the hard part. How would I do something like this? I thought of this, but they both seem like a mess:

When `WSARecv` is called using the WSAOverlapped:
Create a new thread, use `WaitForSingleObject` and pass the `hEvent` of the WSAOverlapped structure. When the event is signaled process the data to the managed server and pass the data to the program.

When `WSARecv` is called using the completion routine:
Create a new thread, modify the call to the original function with `lpOperationCompleted` to a new function. Use `SleepEx` to put the thread in an alertable state. When the OperationCompleted is called process the data and pass data back to the program.

*I could post my code but I didn't write because it seems like a bad solution.. So there is not really a point for that.*

I cannot think of a better solution and this seems horrible because when an application calls `WSARecv` a lot (for example a large server using overlapped sockets to handle lots of clients) it creates a new thread for every call and that just seems like a bad idea.

So how can I do such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to create a thread for each overlapped IO call.

When overlapped operations are used, they either have an associated event (which you can safely ignore), a completion routine, or are associated with an I/O Completion port.

To handle the first two cases you should hook both [`WSARecv()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`WSAGetOverlappedResult()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you need to handle the last, you'll also need to hook [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Now, when you get a call to `WSARecv()`, for the event case, you do nothing special there (except possibly save some information in relation to the `lpOverlapped`, eg. the buffer), and process the data in `WSAGetOverlappedResult()` (which the application must call to get the success/error and bytes transferred.)

If a completion routine is present, save the `lpOverlapped` and `lpCompletionRoutine`, and pass your own completion routine to the real `WSARecv()`.

Your routine should process the data and call the original completion routine.

To handle the I/O completion port case, have `WSARecv()` save `lpOverlapped` and buffers etc., in `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`, call the original, and if the returned overlapped structure matches, handle the data.

You should also note that overlapped operations may complete immediately, in which case the event isn't signaled, the completion routine isn't called, and (IIRC) no completion is queued on the IOCP.

Comment: Okay thank you for the answer, smart tought about the completion routine I don't need to put it in an alertable state the original program should do that. But I don't get why the application must call WSAGetOverlappedResult(), if they pass a valid Event in the WSAOVERLAPPED structure. You can use WaitForSingleObject? Correct me if I'm wrong. (Didn't marked it as answer yet because I don't understand how to handle the first part.)

Comment: You can use an event (and should, completion routines are a pain IIRC), but that only informs you that the operation completed. Unless you call `WSAGetOverlappedResult()` you don't know if the operation completed successfully, or how many bytes were transferred. (as a side note, don't forget that overlapped operations may complete immediately, in which case neither routine nor event will be signaled)

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll try this later if it works I'll accept the answer. 'As a side note, don't forget that overlapped operations may complete immediately, in which case neither routine nor event will be signaled' is it then reliable to check if the buffers are not empty?

Comment: Just check the return value. If eg. an overlapped `WSARecv()` returns 0, then it succeeded, and you can check the arguments for the length and such.

Comment: I used a C# Server as a test target. As I expected it calls WaitForSingleObject internally, not WSAGetOverlappedResult(). If I hook that how would I be able to pair the buffers with hHandle passed in WaitForSingleObject? Because the hHandle is not the same as the hEvent in the WSAOVERLAPPED structure.

Comment: It's probably using an I/O Completion port. I apparently forgot about [`GetQueuedCompletionStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986(v=vs.85).aspx) which I expect you also want to hook. When you you call the real function, you'll get the `WSAOVERLAPPED` structure pointer back.

Comment: Not sure but can't I call from my WaitForSingleObject hook the GetQueuedCompletionStatus to get my WSAOVERLAPPED structure? I mean why should I hook that?

Comment: Not sure why you want to (as calls to `WaitForSingleObject` are common), but if they are using I/O completion ports, and waiting on that, there's no easy way of getting from the wait to the overlapped structure. (Since there can be many sockets/fds associated with the IOCP. also, you might find yourself racing with `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` calls done elsewhere), The rationale for hooking it is that you can track your own overlapped ops, and handle them as they come out of `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`

Comment: Internet Explorer 11 uses WSARecv. But it does not call neither WSAGetOverlappedResult, nor GetQueuedCompletionStatus. lpCompletionRoutine is set to nullptr also. I'm pretty sure all the functions are hooked properly. What can be a reason? Is there any other ways IE can use to get the data when socket operation completes?

Comment: (It does not call GetQueuedCompletionStatusEx either)